# Angular Material Styles not being applied when Running Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I can see that the styles are loaded in the browser, and the material classes are in the css that is loaded.

**Running spa `ng serve`**

[image]

**Running Angular Universal**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**angular.json - architect.build.options**

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    "src/styles.scss",
    "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
],
```

**angular.json - architect.server**

```
"server": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
    "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
        "staging": {
            "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
            ],
            "optimization": false,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "budgets": [
                {
                    "type": "initial",
                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

**server.ts**

Fairly standard `server.ts` file for Angular Universal.

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');


app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

app.get('/health-check', (req, res) => {
  res.send(200);
});

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**package versions**

```
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.4",
"@angular/animations": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/cdk": "~7.3.7",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/http": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/material": "7.3.7",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.7",
"@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.7",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.7",
"@nguniversal/common": "^7.1.1",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.0",
```

Comment: Did you solved this ? If yes How could you post the answer please

Comment: Having the same issue...,

Comment: Same issue here